# NSManagedObjectContext refreshObject causes duplicates in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an issue where if I make changes to a core data object, save then refreshing the object, causes my NSFetchedResultsController to show a duplicate object.  I think I understand what's going on, but I'm looking for someone to confirm, and also to hopefully give some more detail as to why.

To explain in more dtail I have two entities, `Fixture` and `Position`.  A `Fixture` has many `Positions`, and a `Position` belongs to only one `Fixture`.  To reproduce the issue I do the following:

1. Fetch all Positions.
2. Modify some value (any one) on that objects Fixture.  I.E `foo.fixture.name = "foobar"`
3. Save the context
4. Refresh objects by calling `context.refreshAllObjects`, or `context.refreshObject(foo, mergeChanges: false/true)`.

I have a tableview using a fetched results controller which displays Fixures.  After doing the above the tableview will display duplicates for each item (it doesn't matter if I use the delegate methods of the FRC to do the update or I just reload the tableview).

It appears what's happening is that the refresh invalidates the objects that the FRC knows about, while at the same time gets knowledge of another set of objects.  If, as step #5, I call `frc.performFetch()` then the problem goes away.

Other things to note:

- No matter how many times I run the code I only get two of each object (I'm using a random button to trigger it for testing).
- init(entityName, context) is called on my `Fixture` subclass as soon as I access the Fixture property of my object during the next code run (i.e after refresh was called).
- In my sample everything is taking place on the same context (though it happens with child contexts as well)

To give some more context as to how I got myself in this situation in the first place users can click on a fixture in the list and then ultimately narrow down on a single position a few screens later where they can perform actions that modify the fixture.  There are other active areas of the application at this point that are listening to the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and I want them to update their objects so they can display the correct data, which is why I was calling refresh.

I've dug around in the docs and I can't see anything that specifically explains my theory that updating the context causes NSFetchedResultsController to have invalid objects. Can anyone shed some light on this behavior?

Comment: If you're using `NSFetchedResultsController` and having implemented the delegate methods the controller will track all changes and update the UI accordingly. Then there is no need for an explicit refresh.

Comment: The explicit refresh happens someplace completely independent of the `NSFetchedResultsController`. Changes can happen due to real time server updates (in the background). So on pages after the one that uses the FRC I need to have the most updated information, which is why I ask the context to fresh the object.

Answer (score 0):

First, you **really** should not be overriding `-init...` on a `NSManagedObject`.  That is one of the methods that you are strongly discouraged from overriding and can very easily be the source of your issues.

Second, your entire UI should be using a single instance of the `NSManagedObjectContext` that is associated to the main queue and therefore there should only be **ONE** instance of any particular entity in your UI.  If you have multiple contexts you are just making things more complicated for yourself.  If you are using a single context keep in mind that no matter how many times you fetch an object against that context you will get the exact same pointer back.

The `NSFetchedResultsController` will never create objects, it only fetches and provides them for display.  Therefore the `NSFetchedResultsController` is only reporting the fact that you have created this duplication somewhere else in your code.

Now some questions, do these duplicates get pushed down to disk?

Can you see them in the store file on disk?

When you re-launch your application are the duplicates still there?

When you put a print in your custom `-init` methods on the `NSManagedObject`; do they fire more than once?

Comment: To clarify I didn't implement init, I only used a breakpoint to track down who was inserting the duplicate. So what's happening is init is called the first time I explicitly insert the object.  Then it gets called one more time when I change the property after the refresh. The duplicates don't get pushed down to disk, I verified that by looking at the sqlite file directly, and so when I reload the app the duplicates are gone.

Comment: Are you certain these are duplicates and not an error in display?  If they are not getting pushed to disk that points to a display error in your table view rather than a creation error.  Check the `objectID` for each and see if it is the exact same.  How many contexts are active in your app?

Comment: Two contexts, essentially the same as what's in your book.  The object id's are different, and the "old" object returned by the FRC has an object id that returns true for the temporary id property.

Comment: How are the contexts associated? Parent/Child?  Which context are you resetting?  Is your UI using a single context?